# Model Contracts/Interfaces in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, interface, phpunit, tdd

What is the most Laravel way to impose an interface or contract on a factory mock of a model?

For example, let's say I have a model `Dog`.  I use a factory to mock it, and I write a test for it.  I want to make sure that if I mock an instance that does not conform to the contract/interface, an error is thrown.

\App\Dog.php:

```
class Dog extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'dogs';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'breed' ]; // Dogs must have both of these
}
```

database/factories/ModelFactory.php

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name // no mention of breed, which is required
    ];
});
```

tests/DogTest.php

```
class RoadshowUnitTest extends TestCase
{
   /** @test **/
   public function i_should_be_able_to_make_a_dog()
   {
       $dog = factory(App\Roadshow::class, 1)->make();
       // ... internal type assertions go here
   }
}
```

When I run this test, I should get some kind of error; the factory should not be able to produce a `Dog` at all, since it is missing an important field.  How do I impose the requirement on the Model, and anything that uses it (like the factory)?

Comment: When you say that it's "required", how do you mean? A database constraint, validation in the controller, etc?

Comment: @jackel414  If there are different levels of "required", whatever is needed to register 'breed' as a property without with any instance of `Dog` (like from the factory) cannot exist.  Necessary for creating an instance, in other words.

Answer (score 1):

The model factory just creates a new instance of the model object you pass it and assigns values to the attributes that you specify (in this case, just the 'name' attribute). Just as you can do `$user = new User;` and instantiate an empty user object, your factory can have as few attributes as you want when you run `make`.

To ensure that a persisted instance of that model class has the appropriate data attributes, you can: add validation logic that validates request data (in a custom request class or in your controller), or apply constraints to your database table that holds the model data. Ideally you would do both.

Using the `make` command is the same as doing `new Model`, meaning the data is not saved to the database yet (if you want it persisted you can do `save()` after `make()`, or use `create()` in place of `make()`). Therefore, any database constraints you have in place will not come into play. Similarly, since it's not an HTTP request (and not calling a controller method), any validation logic you have is also not being hit.

Sorry this is kind of wordy - short answer is that the model factory itself does not validate your data.

Comment: Can the Model factory be forced to implement an interface?

Comment: A model class can definitely be set up to implement an interface (if you look at Laravel's base Model class you'll see it implements a number of interfaces). However, it's not the model factory that's implementing it - the factory simply news up the class itself.